# How to filter nested aggregation with its parent's value (reverse)?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm struggling with filtering nested aggregations with value from higher level element. I've applied hint for place and action to be taken in the code below.

The case is that I want to have one aggregation per path, so there should not be created another aggregation with path: 'events' with inner aggregation for roles if possible.

```
GET _search 
{ 
  "filter": {},
  "aggs": {
    "events.role.name5": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "inner": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "events.role"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filtered.aggs": {
              "filter": {
                 // Here I'd have something like:
                 "terms": {
                    "events.id": [
                       448,
                       435
                    ]
                 }
                 // of course that does not work because of context. 
              },
              "aggs": {
                "events.role.name": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "events.role.name",
                    "size": 50
                  }
                },
                "events.role.name_count": {
                  "cardinality": {
                    "field": "events.role.name"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "events.name12": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "inner": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "events"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filtered.aggs": {
              "filter": {
                "terms": {
                  "events.id": [
                    448,
                    435
                  ]
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "events.name": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "events.name",
                    "size": 5
                  }
                },
                "events.name_count": {
                  "cardinality": {
                    "field": "events.name"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 5,
  "_source": [
    "events",
    "address"
  ]
}
```

**CASE IS** to achieve same result **NOT USING THIS**:

```
"aggs": {
        "inner": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "events"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filtered.aggs": {
              "filter": {
                "terms": {
                  "events.id": [
                    448,
                    435
                  ]
                }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "inner": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "events.role"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "filtered.aggs": {
                  "filter": {},
                  "aggs": {
                    "events.role.name": {
                      "terms": {
                        "field": "events.role.name",
                        "size": 50
                      }
                    },
                    "events.role.name_count": {
                      "cardinality": {
                        "field": "events.role.name"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Comment: Actually I did not. I've changed structure to simplify access to relevant aggregations